# What is "with" used for in PHP?

Tags: php

I have come across this line in the eloquent ORM library:

```
return with(new static)->newQuery();
```

I've never seen "with" used before, and cannot find it in the PHP documentation. I'm guessing "with" is a stop-word in most searches, so I am not even getting close.

Never having encountered "with" in many years of programming PHP, I feel like I'm missing out. What does it do? I did come across one passing comment regarding the ORM, that mentioned "with" is no longer needed in PHP-5.4, but that was as much as was said. If that is accurate, it would be good to know what the PHP-5.4 equivalent is.

Update: Details supporting the answer:-

I found this helper function in Laravel's Immuminate/Support/helpers.php helper script:

```
if ( ! function_exists('with'))
{
    /**
     * Return the given object. Useful for chaining.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $object
     * @return mixed
     */
    function with($object)
    {
        return $object;
    }
}
```

as mentioned in a few of the answers. That global-scope function allows an object to be created and methods run in t, in one statement. It is (somehow) registered in the composer autoload_files.php script when Laravel is installed, so it gets loaded on every page, even though it contains no classes.

Thanks all. It pays not to assume that everything *must be* a namespaced class in modern frameworks.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a custom function?

Comment: `with` isn't a reserved word in PHP.  They just named a function `with`.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a workaround for something along the lines of `new Foo()->newQuery()` not working in some version of PHP...?  ('Tho I think it works in 5.2, so I'm not sure what version)

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: @Izkata: The ability to do `new Foo()->newQuery()` was added in PHP 5.4.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Nevermind then.  I've been off our PHP-based product (which is stuck on 5.2) for over a year now; I must be misremembering.  (It uses an ugly mixture of `new Foo()` and `Bar::create()` depending on the class involved)

Comment: @perdeu it's not eager loading, which involves a `with()` method on one of the ORM classes, but it's interesting to read up anyway. This `with()` turns out to be a global scope function.

Comment: I guess this is where IDEs can be useful: a simple ctrl-click would solve this _mystery_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a function that will look something like this:

```
function with($obj) { 
    return $obj; 
}
```

It's shorter version and more readable version for `new ExampleObj()->newQuery()`. 
`with` function is not build in PHP. It's workaround for older versions than PHP 5.4. As @Rocket Hazmat pointed in PHP 5.4+ you can do just `new ExampleObj()->newQuery()` so `with` function here allow you to keep readable backward compatibility.

Comment: In PHP 5.4+, you can do `new ExampleObj()->newQuery()`, but not in older versions.

Comment: Yup, that's true. I'll change my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `with` function is a helper provided by Laravel as [documented here](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#miscellaneous).  The best documentation is [the code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php#L960-L972) and as you can see, it simply returns the object.  In 5.4 / 5.4 you are better off just surrounding the expression in parens to avoid the overhead of an unnecessary function call.

Answer (score 3):

I think [@Izkata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910452/what-is-with-used-for-in-php#comment29624017_19910452) hit the nail on the head in the comments.

> [I'm guessing] this is a workaround for something along the lines of `new Foo()->newQuery()` not working in some version of PHP

In PHP 5.4 the following was added:

> Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. `(new Foo)->bar()`.

<sub>(Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)</sub>

So, I'd assume `with` looks something like this:

```
function with($x){
    return $x;
}
```

In PHP 5.4+, you can do `(new static)->newQuery()`, but with an older version, you can't.  `with` is probably there so you can do `with(new static)->newQuery()`, which will work in any PHP version.